# How to change view-parameter within controller?

Tags: php, symfony

This is the code that gets executed (as displayed in "code behind this page" section):

Controller Code

```
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        $name = "whatever";
        $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello.html.twig',
          array('name' => '123'));
        //return array('name' => 'abc');
    }
```

Template Code

```
{% extends "AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title "Hello " ~ name %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>xHello {{ name }}!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

The output is

```
xHello Raffael!
```

The URL: http://192.168.177.128/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/Raffael

---

And here is my problem:

When I uncomment the return within controller then "Raffael" is replaced with "abc" as expected.

But according to the [Quicktour](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony2-QuickTour.pdf&ei=_T8kTuLBHcP2sgbk_umgAg&usg=AFQjCNF1S-bcQtV96NHsk2uRyrsCDZNHNw&sig2=houJTffxsc5RO73RANAz7w) it is possible to determine the values of variables within the template via the render-Method.

> To render a template in Symfony, use the render method from within a
>   controller and pass it any variables needed in the template:
>
> $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello.html.twig', array( 'name' =>
>   $name, ));

What's wrong?

Comment: FYI: 
http://192.168.177.128/ is only accesible on your local network

Comment: correct! 100 points and the brand new washing machine go to afuzzyllamaaaaa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down the quick tour implicitely reveales that you have to return the output of render:

```
public function helloAction($name)
{
  return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:hello.html.twig', 
    array('name' => '123'));
}
```